# Invoke-Command with -credentials

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I want to invoke a command on a remote server, I do not want to have to put in the password to run the script. I've tried encrypting the password and storing it in a txt file.

```
 $username = "Mydomain\service.account"
 $password = cat C:\username-password-encrypted.txt | convertto-securestring
 $cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential - argumentlist $username, $password
 Invoke-command $cred -Computer myserver -scriptblock {param([string]$LocalUser); Add-PSSnapin Citrix* ; Get-BrokerSession -max 10000 | Where-Object brokeringusername -eq  "mydomain\$($LocalUser)" | Stop-BrokerSession} -ArgumentList $user
```

Here is the error I get

```
 Invoke-Command : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'System.Management.Automation.PSCredential'.
 At \\uncpath\citrix\Installation Media\Citrix\Ticketing_script\Ticketing_Script - Copy (3).ps1:70 char:1
+ Invoke-command $cred -Computer MyServer -scriptblock {param([s ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Command],   ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId :   PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand
```

There has to be an easier way to run this command on myserver without having to put in the password every time.

Comment: Remove the space between - and argumentlist in line 3

Comment: When I do that it no longer reads in the creds of the user thats running the script.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to specify the `-Credential` parameter:

```
 Invoke-command -Credential $cred -Computer myserver -scriptblock {param([string]$LocalUser); Add-PSSnapin Citrix* ; Get-BrokerSession -max 10000 | Where-Object brokeringusername -eq  "mydomain\$($LocalUser)" | Stop-BrokerSession} -ArgumentList $user
```

Comment: I've tried that

Here is the error I get when I add the -Credential
New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "PSCredential" and the argument count: "2".
At \\MyDomain\citrix\Installation Media\Citrix\Ticketing_script\Ticketing_Script.ps1:110 char:9
+ $cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($userna ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

Answer (score 0):

4 years later but here goes:

Frode F. had the right idea in the comments. Your third line has `- argumentlist` but it must be `-ArgumentList`, otherwise it will throw `New-Object : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'ArgumentList'.`

Also, when I copy and run your exact code it does not throw the same error which leads me to believe that the code you're running is not the same as the one you've written here. Here are the different errors you've received and the reasons for them:

**Incorrect syntax**

```
A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'System.Management.Automation.PSCredential'.
```

This means that you've not specified the flag correctly, Powershell thinks you're using a flag or parameter called System.Management.Automation.PSCredential. You can simulate this by adding a hyphen like `New-Object -TypeName - System.Management.Automation.PSCredential` and see for yourself, so your syntax is wrong *somewhere*.

**Incorrect password format**

```
Cannot find an overload for "PSCredential" and the argument count: "2".
```

This means that the `$Password` is not in the correct format. You're importing a file called `password-encrypted.txt` but after this you pass it to `ConvertTo-SecureString`. Are you sure that the information in the `password-encrypted.txt` file is passed to both `ConvertTo-SecureString` and then to `ConvertFrom-SecureString` before you saved it, like so?

```
"MyPassword" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Out-File "C:\username-password-encrypted.txt"
```

For more information on how to deal with passwords in Powershell, see this post that goes into detail on how to do credentials in Powershell:

https://www.pdq.com/blog/secure-password-with-powershell-encrypting-credentials-part-1/

**In conclusion**

If you run the code you've provided here using both `-ArgumentList` (instead of `- argumentlist`) and `-Credentials $creds` like others have suggested it should run fine. You're most likely not running the code that you've provided here because with these two adjustments the code runs.